# MS Word version 16.35, MacBook Pro 2019, copy/paste no longer pastes footnotes!

Tags: ms-office, copy-paste

I'm having a strange situation.  I am an academic and I am constantly revising documents with footnotes in MS Word.  I'm using Word on a MacBook Pro 2019.  All of a sudden, the footnotes disappear when I copy/paste between documents or within a document. The text pastes, but the footnotes are missing and are nowhere to be found.  I tried different documents, restarting my computer, but it's still happening.  Can somebody help?

EDIT: I just discovered that I can get the footnote to appear but I have to select "match destination formatting" in the copy/paste option box.  I never had to do this before today, so if anyone has any ideas as to what happened, I'd be VERY grateful.